# Mysql - how to insert a dot after the second character in each row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to add a point character to a column each rows, after second character in mysql.

For example :

I have a column data like this :

```
         30234234234
         36234234234
         37234234234
```

I need to make this :

```
         30.234234234
         36.234234234
         37.234234234
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with simple string manipulation and `concat()`:

```
select concat(left(data, 2), '.', substr(data, 3))
```

Or use `insert()`:

```
select insert(data, 3, 0, '.')
```

Reference:

- [CONCAT(str1,str2,...)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)
- [LEFT(str,len)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left)
- [SUBSTR(str,pos)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)
- [INSERT(str,pos,len,newstr)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_insert)